# Images corrupt after git push

Tags: image, git, corruption, git-push

I added some .png images to my git repo and then pushed them to my remote repository. I noticed that the images are in the remote repository, but they are broken.

In order to verify this, I compared the binary data for the images on my local and my remote repos. I also ran the `file` command on images in both repos.

### Image on *local* repository

First 10 Lines of Binary data:

> 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452
>   0000 0019 0000 0014 0806 0000 0078 7796
>   bd00 0000 1974 4558 7453 6f66 7477 6172
>   6500 4164 6f62 6520 496d 6167 6552 6561
>   6479 71c9 653c 0000 0373 6954 5874 584d
>   4c3a 636f 6d2e 6164 6f62 652e 786d 7000
>   0000 0000 3c3f 7870 6163 6b65 7420 6265
>   6769 6e3d 22ef bbbf 2220 6964 3d22 5735
>   4d30 4d70 4365 6869 487a 7265 537a 4e54
>   637a 6b63 3964 223f 3e20 3c78 3a78 6d70

Result of `file` command:

> bundles/admin/public/images/messages-icon.png: PNG image data, 24 x 16, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced

### Image pushed to *remote* repository

First 10 Lines of Binary data:

> 8950 4e47 0a1a 0a00 0000 0d49 4844 5200
>   0000 1900 0000 1408 0600 0000 7877 96bd
>   0000 0019 7445 5874 536f 6674 7761 7265
>   0041 646f 6265 2049 6d61 6765 5265 6164
>   7971 c965 3c00 0003 7369 5458 7458 4d4c
>   3a63 6f6d 2e61 646f 6265 2e78 6d70 0000
>   0000 003c 3f78 7061 636b 6574 2062 6567
>   696e 3d22 efbb bf22 2069 643d 2257 354d
>   304d 7043 6568 6948 7a72 6553 7a4e 5463
>   7a6b 6339 6422 3f3e 203c 783a 786d 706d

Result of `file` command:

> bundles/admin/public/images/notifications-icon.png: data

Why would this be happening? I searched all over google and this site for answers but have found none.

Comment: Given `8950 4e47 0d0a 1a...` vs `8950 4e47 0a1a` it's immediately obvious (well... :-) ) that something thought this was a text file and turned CR-LF (`0d0a`) into LF-only (`0a`).  Are you (or they) using the `core.eol` attribute and/or other git attributes to manage end-of-line normalization?

Comment: I think so, we have `* text eol=lf` in our `.gitattributes` file, and core.eol is not set

Comment: I also have .png listed as binary in my `.gitattributes` file

Comment: I've never actually used git's conversions, but it sounds like your side is set up right, so I'd check the remote's setup in case it's somehow broken.

Comment: What's `git check-attr --all -- path/to/png` say?

Comment: Pff, took me all day to figure this out. \0/ Thanks.

Answer (score 65):

I had this issue too - here's a generic .gitattributes that looks generally safe for php web repos that worked for me:  https://github.com/Danimoth/gitattributes/blob/master/Web.gitattributes

running git check-attr --all -- path/to/png before and after adding the new gitattributes showed that the image file was originally treated as a text file, and now it's binary (note I had to commit/push the .gitattributes file for it to take effect on remote)

In case the link goes dead:

```
# These settings are for any web project

# Handle line endings automatically for files detected as text
# and leave all files detected as binary untouched.
# * text=auto
# NOTE - originally I had the above line un-commented.  it caused me a lot of grief related to line endings because I was dealing with WordPress plugins and the website changing line endings out if a user modified a plugin through the web interface.  commenting this line out seems to have alleviated the git chaos where simply switching to a branch caused it to believe 500 files were modified.

#
# The above will handle all files NOT found below
#

#
## These files are text and should be normalized (Convert crlf => lf)
#

# source code
*.php text
*.css text
*.sass text
*.scss text
*.less text
*.styl text
*.js text
*.coffee text
*.json text
*.htm text
*.html text
*.xml text
*.svg text
*.txt text
*.ini text
*.inc text
*.pl text
*.rb text
*.py text
*.scm text
*.sql text
*.sh text
*.bat text

# templates
*.ejs text
*.hbt text
*.jade text
*.haml text
*.hbs text
*.dot text
*.tmpl text
*.phtml text

# server config
.htaccess text

# git config
.gitattributes text
.gitignore text
.gitconfig text

# code analysis config
.jshintrc text
.jscsrc text
.jshintignore text
.csslintrc text

# misc config
*.yaml text
*.yml text
.editorconfig text

# build config
*.npmignore text
*.bowerrc text

# Heroku
Procfile text
.slugignore text

# Documentation
*.md text
LICENSE text
AUTHORS text


#
## These files are binary and should be left untouched
#

# (binary is a macro for -text -diff)
*.png binary
*.jpg binary
*.jpeg binary
*.gif binary
*.ico binary
*.mov binary
*.mp4 binary
*.mp3 binary
*.flv binary
*.fla binary
*.swf binary
*.gz binary
*.zip binary
*.7z binary
*.ttf binary
*.eot binary
*.woff binary
*.pyc binary
*.pdf binary
```

Comment: very, very helpful to fix corrupt images pushed to a repo. thanks!

Comment: I've made an alteration from what the original link I found posted - I just made a quick edit - see lines 5 and 6 regarding * text=auto.

Comment: I had a similar issue and this solved it. Im going to use this .gitattributes in all my projects going forwards. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> *.png binary

in `.gitattribute` worked after images were reuploaded.

You can add all images by executing `git add *.png --force`