# Cloning a Git project: status of images is suddenly turned to Modified

Tags: git, github

I have a frontend project which contains some images. It behaves totally okay in development mode on the Machine A.

Once I succesfully push all images into Github, none of them can be previewed on the Github page. These images are just jpg or png files of the size upto 100KB.

I have cloned the project to the Machine B. Suddenly, despite these images are of the same size as on Github, none of them can be opened. Windows photo viewer says "not in correct format".

The only way I can push images onto Github without issues is to upload on the Github page. But in this case, as soon as I clone the project or pull the code, images get automatically turned into status Modified, even though I do nothing with them. Apart from that, if I commit the change and push, none of them can be previewed again!

This is how the fresh clone looks like, whereas I have done nothing.

[image]

Also, here is .gitattributes

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text eol=lf
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `git diff -- path/to/comingsoon.png` (please update the path as well) - I can provide an answer based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen guys. I finally solved it. It is still caused by eol. Git just regards images as text rather than binary. Simply modified `.gitattributes`.

[Images corrupt after git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411981/images-corrupt-after-git-push?%20Maybe%20git%20takes%20png%20as%20text)